# Multiplication of different subsets with different data in R

Tags: r, subset, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I have a large dataset, which I splitted up into subsets. For each subsets, I have to do the same calculations but with different numbers. Example:

```
Main Table
x a b c d
A 1 2 4 5 
A 4 5 1 7
A 3 5 6 2
B 4 5 2 9
B 3 5 2 8
C 4 2 5 2
C 1 9 6 9
C 1 2 3 4
C 6 3 6 2

 Additional Table for A
  a b c d
A 5 1 6 1

Additional Table for B
  a b c d
B 1 5 2 6

Additional Table for C
  a c c d
C 8 2 4 1
```

I need to multiply all rows A in the Main Table with the values from Additional Table for A, all rows B in the Main table with the values from B and all rows B in the main table with values from C. It is completely fine to merge the additional tables into a combined one, if this makes the solution easier.

I thought about a for-loop but I am not able to put the different multiplicators (from the Additional Tables) into the code. Since there is a large number of subgroups, coding each multiplication manually should be avoided. How do I do this multiplications?

Comment: Share some of your data to work with:  `dput(your_data)`  Paste that into your question.

Comment: I just noticed that you commented something on my post and deleted it.  Couldn't catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start with the addition table as `addDf` and main table as `df`:

```
addDf
  x a b c d
A A 5 1 6 1
B B 1 5 2 6
C C 8 2 4 1
```

We can use a merge and the by-element multiplication of matrix as,

```
df[-1] <- merge(addDf, data.frame(x = df[1]), by = "x")[-1] * df[order(df[1]), -1]
df
  x  a  b  c  d
1 A  5  2 24  5
2 A 20  5  6  7
3 A 15  5 36  2
4 B  4 25  4 54
5 B  3 25  4 48
6 C 32  4 20  2
7 C  8 18 24  9
8 C  8  4 12  4
9 C 48  6 24  2
```

Note: Borrowed a little syntax sugar from @akrun as `df[-1]` assignment.

Comment: `merge` seems to sort the "by" column of the two "data.frame"s; i.e. the `* df[-1]` won't work for not ordered `df$x`. A similar `merge`-y alternative could be `addDf[match(df$x, addDf$x), -1] * df[-1]` or something like that

Comment: @alexis_laz. yep, thanks for pointing that out. Just updated a sorted version, I agree your approach is even a short one.

Comment: @ Psidom This works fine. Unfortunately, my data.frame df is way larger and contains hundrets of columns unrelated to the multiplication. When using the calculations on the real data, I get the message that '*' is defined for dataframes of the same size. What is the solution for that?

Comment: You can explicitly specify the columns you want to modify. For example, if you just want modify columns from 2 to 5 as in your case, you can do `df[2:5] <- merge(addDf, data.frame(x = df[1]), by = "x")[-1] * df[order(df[1]), 2:5]`. In this way you just extract the numeric columns which have the same dimension as your additional table, multiply them and modify them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` after `split`ting the main data 'df' (assuming that all of the datasets are `data.frame`s.

```
df[-1] <- unsplit(Map(function(x,y) x*y[col(x)], 
                     split(df[-1], df$x),
                     list(unlist(dfA), unlist(dfB), unlist(dfC))), df$x)
df
#  x  a  b  c  d
#1 A  5  2 24  5
#2 A 20  5  6  7
#3 A 15  5 36  2
#4 B  4 25  4 54
#5 B  3 25  4 48
#6 C 32  4 20  2
#7 C  8 18 24  9
#8 C  8  4 12  4
#9 C 48  6 24  2
```

---

Or we can use a faster option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(do.call(rbind, list(dfA, dfB, dfC)), keep.rownames=TRUE)[df, 
 .(a= a*i.a, b= b*i.b, c = c*i.c, d= d*i.d),  on = c('rn' = 'x'), by = .EACHI], 1, 'x')[]
#   x  a  b  c  d
#1: A  5  2 24  5
#2: A 20  5  6  7
#3: A 15  5 36  2
#4: B  4 25  4 54
#5: B  3 25  4 48
#6: C 32  4 20  2
#7: C  8 18 24  9
#8: C  8  4 12  4
#9: C 48  6 24  2
```

The above would be difficult if there many columns, in that case, we could use `mget` to retrieve the columns and do the `*` on the `i.` columns with `Map`

```
setDT(do.call(rbind, list(dfA, dfB, dfC)), keep.rownames=TRUE)[df,  
     Map(`*`, mget(names(df)[-1]), mget(paste0("i.", names(df)[-1]))) ,
          on = c('rn' = 'x'), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: @ akrun: Thank you very much, but I also get different results. It seems that the addDF table is read (and therefore multiplied) from the last value to the first one.

Comment: @nous.calc  Looks like I am getting the same results as the other post (where my id is also mentioned in context with some sugar).  Here, I am assuming all the datasets are `data.frame`